# loop over sub-folder in R

Tags: r

I'm working in a folder containing multiple sub-folders within R environment. I wanted a loop over the multiple sub-folders and then call an R script in each sub-folder for execution. I came up with the code below. But my code seems to be adding "." to the list of sub-folders and I got errors ("Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  invalid 'description' argument"). Although there is no problem with the R scripts being called.

code:

```
for (x in list.dirs()){
  folder <- list.dirs(x)
  script <- paste(folder,"/","process.R", sep="")
  source(script)
}
```

What is the correct way to do this? I think what I'm doing may not be right.

Comment: What prevents you from removing the . (current folder) from the folder variable, if you think this is the culprit? `folder <- folder[-1]` should work. It is hard to give an answer since your example is not reproducible. Have you tried running the loop manually? Your script variable seems to contain a list of string lines, each of them containing a sub-folder path ending with process.R. I don't see how you can `source()` that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, you have a script called `process.R` in multiple subfolders. You want to run all these scripts. If this is the case, I imagine the following would work:

```
folder <- list.dirs() # this assumes being in the main folder, otherwise specify the path
folder <- folder[-1]  # comment this out if the main folder also contains the script
script.paths <- paste(folder,"/","process.R", sep="")

for (i in script.paths) {
source(i)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Does something like the following work:

```
# Folder containing sub-folders
parent.folder <- "/home/tony/Desktop/test"

# Sub-folders
sub.folders <- list.dirs(parent.folder, recursive=TRUE)[-1]

# R script file paths
r.scripts <- file.path(sub.folders, "process.R")

# Run scripts in sub-folders 
for(script in r.scripts) {
  source(script)
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. Using Maxim and Tony's scripts, the R scripts were executed, but for some reason the lines at the top of the code were not executed, instead execution started somewhere down the bottom, resulting in some "objects not found".

Comment: @user27976 You need to sort the script location list according to your criteria. It is impossible to advise you further without having a reproducible example.